# android:how to check if application is running in background

Tags: android

I am newbie to android. I have client server based application. Server keeps on sending the update notifications to client after every single minute and at client side my app receive those updates and display it using Toast. But now my problem is whenever my client app goes into the background server keeps on sending the update notifications and my client display it as if the application is in foreground. I am not getting how to check that application is running in background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles is a description of the Life Cycle of an android application.

The method onPause() gets called when the activity goes into the background. So you can deactivate the update notifications in this method.

Comment: This will also deactivate notifications from being sent if another activity is started from that activity.

Comment: In my project I've too many activities how to know app is in background ?

Answer (score 37):

**Update, see this first:**

[Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background)

---

To check if your application is sent to background, you can call this code on `onPause()` on every activity in your application:

```
 /**
   * Checks if the application is being sent in the background (i.e behind
   * another application's Activity).
   * 
   * @param context the context
   * @return <code>true</code> if another application will be above this one.
   */
  public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
      if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

For this to work you should include this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: Hi @peceps I want to inform you that with Android 4.4 (or N5) this method is not working properly. topActivity and context packages are equals... can you please update your answer?

Comment: @StErMi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background

Comment: The method [`getRunningTasks (int maxNum)`, was deprecated in the API level 21(LOLLIPOP)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)), for security reasons, the possibility of leaking personal information to third-party applications. (If you use this method to be aware that it will not be supported for future Android versions).

Comment: What does this line do? `!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())`

Answer (score 3):

**Only for API level 14 and above**

You can use [ComponentCallbacks2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) to an `activity`, `service`, etc.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ComponentCallbacks2 {
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onLowMemory() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
     if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        // app is in background
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) in ActivityManager .