# Check if an application is in background

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)
>   [android:how to check if application is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183932/androidhow-to-check-if-application-is-running-in-background)

I would like to start/stop my service when an app is launched (YouTube, Video App, every other app).
Is it possible to do. If so, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, misread your question.

When your application is backgrounded (which you can detect with `onPause`) you can start your service. In your service you'll want to detect the application that is currently in foreground.

You can do that by [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service).

Comment: I know when my app goes in background. Please read the question again.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread your question. You want to know when a DIFFERENT application is running in the foreground. I've edited my question.