# Check if Android app is in Background?

Tags: android, events, background

I have done lots of searching but did not find any suitable answer for this. Problem is like this :

suppose I start android project having activities A, B, C and i need to catch event when whole app goes to background after Home button press (irrespective of activity).

When user starts app again it resumed from Activity stack maintained by android. This event i want to catch and show toast to user "Your app is now active".

This toast show not be visible while switching one screen to another, it should be only visible for the first time whenever user come back on app again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something after days effort. Hopefully it will useful in some context.

```
/**
* Checks if the application is being sent in the background (i.e behind
* another application's Activity).
* 
* @param context the context
* @return <code>true</code> if another application will be above this one.
*/
public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
  ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
}
```

For this to work you should include this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

For more detail. refer : [android:how to check if application is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183932/androidhow-to-check-if-application-is-running-in-background)

Comment: Hello, as you mentioned you have 3 activities A B C so have you written this piece of code in each of the activity????
Or is there an Activity/Class which stays as long as app is active

Answer (score 0):

When Home button is pressed, **onStop** method is called in your activity.So you can set one `boolean` there in sharedpreferences and also override **onstart** check it manually and put a Toast there if boolean is true.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {

       //set flag true in shared preferences

    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried with shared preferences by overrideing onStop()?

Comment: i have tried that.. but according to my requirement while switching between activities toast should not be visible, it should only visible when app comes in active state again. onStop  and onStart works while switching activities.

Comment: see my updated answer. it will uswful to detect home button click event

Comment: This was security flaw in android, which is removed in ICS (>=4.0). Now we can not catch HOME event. Only backPress and Menu event is available to catch.

anyways thanks Brijesh for your answer. :-)

Answer (score -1):

This method is called when app is active again. Write your toast in there.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Yes but I understand the question like this:  He wants to show the toast when the app resumed. so this is the right method for it.

Comment: Well, if you only want to check the home button, check this out:http://nisha113a5.blogspot.nl/  but it is a bit dangerous because your app could go on the background due to several reasons, so the best way to check that is using the Activity life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html